# Showing multiple markers on google mapfragment via an array list

Tags: android-studio, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, mapfragment

I have an arraylist of latitude and longitude and I am trying to put a marker at different places using the values of my array list; but nothing is showing on map when I run the below code.

```
for(int x = 0 ; x < latlong.size(); x++){
     place1 = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latlong.get(x).longitude,latlong.get(x).latitude)).title("location");
     mMap.addMarker(place1);
     mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlong.get(0), 14));
}
```

Comment: 1. check the `latlong.size()` - it should be greater than `0`
2. check the `latlong.get(x).longitude` and `latlong.get(x).latitude` - they should be reasonable;
3.Move `mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlong.get(0), 14));` line outside of for loop

Comment: First parameter of the constructor of LatLng should be latitude, the second longitude. You mixed that up in your code.